# Prevent child's padding/borders from overflowing parent

Tags: html, css

Demo of problem on [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/usoqome/2/edit)

I want the child, including it's padding and borders, to be fully contained in the parent.

I want a solution that allows me to specify the child's width as 100%, as in the demo.

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot of issue]

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    some content
  </div>  
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.container {
  max-width:400px;
  padding:0px;
  border:1px solid green;
}

.child {
  padding: 10px; 
  width:100%;
  border:30px solid #f2f2f2;
  text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box`. Include the `-moz-` prefix for Firefox which still requires it:

```
.child {
  padding: 10px; 
  width:100%;
  border:30px solid #f2f2f2;
  text-align:right;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```